# Why is "robes" used in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> The oldest boy came striding into sight. He had already changed into his billowing black Hogwarts **robes**, and Harry noticed a shiny silver badge on his chest with the letter P on it.
>   <sup><sub>(Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)</sub></sup>

Does *robes* mean just a formal gown, whether it is consisted of a couple of pieces or just one?
Does *robes* mean something that consists of more than one piece of gown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OED's definition **1:a** is the one OP will be familiar with - *A long loose outer garment reaching to the feet or ankles; a gown.* But the sense here is their definition **1:b**...

> *In plural*. **Outer clothes in general, esp. long, loose-fitting ones.**
>    Sometimes difficult to distinguish from the plural of sense 1a.